# How to overwrite a file uploading to SharePoint with Microsoft Graph

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a Python script that will upload a file to Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph but it gives me a `500` status code error when I try to upload the same file twice.

Here is the code for the function that uploads the file:

```
def upload_file(session,filename,driveid,folder):

    """Upload a file to Sharepoint.

    """
    fname_only = os.path.basename(filename)

    # create the Graph endpoint to be used

    endpoint = f'drives/{driveid}/root:/{folder}/{fname_only}:/createUploadSession'

    start_response = session.put(api_endpoint(endpoint))
    json_response = start_response.json()
    upload_url = json_response["uploadUrl"]

# upload in chunks

    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as fhandle:
        start_byte = 0
        while True:
            file_content = fhandle.read(10*1024*1024)
            data_length = len(file_content)
            if data_length <= 0:
                break

            end_byte = start_byte + data_length - 1
            crange = "bytes "+str(start_byte)+"-"+str(end_byte)+"/"+str(filesize)
            print(crange)
            chunk_response = session.put(upload_url,
                                         headers={"Content-Length": str(data_length),"Content-Range": crange},
                                         data=file_content)
            if not chunk_response.ok:
                print(f'<Response [{chunk_response.status_code}]>')
                pprint.pprint(chunk_response.json()) # show error message
                break

            start_byte = end_byte + 1

    return chunk_response
```

Here is the output for the first run:

```
bytes 0-10485759/102815295
bytes 10485760-20971519/102815295
bytes 20971520-31457279/102815295
bytes 31457280-41943039/102815295
bytes 41943040-52428799/102815295
bytes 52428800-62914559/102815295
bytes 62914560-73400319/102815295
bytes 73400320-83886079/102815295
bytes 83886080-94371839/102815295
bytes 94371840-102815294/102815295
```

Here is the output for the second run:

```
bytes 0-10485759/102815295
bytes 10485760-20971519/102815295
bytes 20971520-31457279/102815295
bytes 31457280-41943039/102815295
bytes 41943040-52428799/102815295
bytes 52428800-62914559/102815295
bytes 62914560-73400319/102815295
bytes 73400320-83886079/102815295
bytes 83886080-94371839/102815295
bytes 94371840-102815294/102815295
<Response [500]>
{'error': {'code': 'generalException',
           'message': 'An unspecified error has occurred.'}}
```

I guess I could figure out how to delete the file before I overwrite it but it would be nice to preserve history since Sharepoint keeps versions.

Thanks for any help on this.

Bobby

p.s. I have been hacking the code in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app to get it to upload a file to SharePoint so some of the code in the function is from Microsoft's sample application.

Comment: I ended up adding code to delete the file before uploading over it and that resolved the issue. https://github.com/bobbydurrett/copyfiletosharepoint It still would be nice to know why I get the 500 error overwriting a file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone ending up here whilst looking into file name conflict issues, according to the Microsoft article below, if there is a file name collision and you have not correctly specified that it should be replaced, the final byte range upload will fail in the way OP is describing. Hopefully this helps someone.

> Handle upload errors
>
> When the last byte range of a file is uploaded, it is possible for an error to occur. This can be due to a name conflict or quota limitation being exceeded. The upload session will be preserved until the expiration time, which allows your app to recover the upload by explicitly committing the upload session.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online#create-an-upload-session